# Wrong symbols in PHP exception

Tags: php, exception

When I catch an exception during my PHP script, the sentence is well displayed. But specials characters like é,à,è are replaced with wierd symbols.

In the beginning of my PHP script I have `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

I also tried to set `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my html.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about `utf8_encode` function?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: The ut8_encode was the right solution, not the decode one. Thanks !